# type object 'HttpResponse' has no attribute 'User'

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am trying to create projects to currently signed in users. I've tried many different things with my CreateProjectView class however keep running into errors.
My codes are below.

Models.py
[models.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VryOs.png)

Views.py
[views.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7FCA.png)

Database screenshots
[database1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VwTnz.png)
[database2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZMnr.png)

error code
AttributeError: type object 'HttpResponse' has no attribute 'User'
[06/Mar/2021 11:55:09] "POST /add HTTP/1.1" 500 88813

Comment: Are you aware that line 62 in views is the cause of error?, I think instead of HttpResponse it should be HttpRequest

Comment: hello, it then says AttributeError at /add
type object 'HttpRequest' has no attribute 'User'

Comment: Have you tried using `user` instead of `User`?

Comment: yes then it says "AttributeError at /add
type object 'HttpRequest' has no attribute 'user' "

Comment: I updated the post to show my database, everything seems to work except when i go to press add

Comment: Before trying to get my project list to displayer user specific projects, I added 
user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False, related_name="Project")
to my models.py

Comment: is this `AttributeError at /add type object 'HttpRequest' has no attribute 'user'` error resolved?

Comment: no, still getting same error. I'm still trying to figure out why I'm getting this error though

Comment: i think i need to figure out how to request the user from the users table then insert the user id when i create the project but not sure how to go about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On line 62 of your views, change HttpResponse to HttpRequest.

It should be **HttpRquest.user.project.add(self)** instead.

note the lower case i used.

Comment: hello thank you but after using that it says AttributeError at /add
type object 'HttpRequest' has no attribute 'User'

Comment: note the case of my answer. user not User

Comment: right, it still said the same thing however I got past that but now when I create a new project, I get no errors but the project doesn't get added to the database and the page just refreshed.

Comment: Line 61. You are saving without committing, it will not hit the db